# C++ Read file in the background

Tags: c++, multithreading, file, audio

I am implementing an audio player application that pre-buffers a small part of the audio data and reads the rest of the data when it is required to do so, for example when the play command arrives. It's a real time application, to it's really important that theres near zero latency between the play command and the start of the playback.

Example: my audio stream is 10 Mb, I read part of it when the file is selected and start creating a buffer like this:

```
// Stuff to do as soon as the file is selected
// Allocate new memory for the current sample

// contains sample length in number of samples
sampleSize = SampleLib.smp.len; 

// assume it's a 16-bit audio file, each sample is 2 bytes long
byteSize = sampleSize * sizeof(short); 

// Allow 10 extra samples and fill with zeroes
SampleData = new short[sampleSize + 10]();

// PRELOAD_BYTESIZE is set to 65535 bytes
preloadByteSize = byteSize > PRELOAD_BYTESIZE ? PRELOAD_BYTESIZE : byteSize;

// Set pointer in file - WavePointer contains the exact location where the sample data starts in file
fseek(inFile, WavePointer, SEEK_SET); 

// read preloadByteSize from inFile into SampleData
fread(SampleData, 1, preloadByteSize, inFile);
```

At this point my buffer `SampleData` contains only part of the audio data to start playing back as soon as the play command arrives. At the same time, the program should fill the rest of the buffer and continue playing up until the end of the audio sample with no interruption.

```
// Stuff to do as soon the playback starts
// Load the rest of the sample data

// If file is already in memory, avoid reading it again
if (preloadByteSize < ByteSize) 
{
    // Set pointer in file at stample start + preload size
    fseek(fpFile, WavePointers + preloadByteSize, SEEK_SET);

    // read the remaining bytes from inFile and fill the empty part of the buffer
    fread(SampleData + preloadByteSize / sizeof(short), 1, ByteSize - preloadByteSize, inFile);

    // remember the number of loaded bytes
    preloadByteSize = ByteSize;
}
```

I expect that the second part of the code is executed in the background while the file is playing back, but actually it's all serial processing, so playback won't start until the rest of the buffer is loaded, thus retarding the playback.
Ho can I have a background thread that loads the file data without interfering with the audio task? Can I do this with OpenMP?

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows, Linux, some embedded environment?

Comment: Windows and Linux. This code should be multi-platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do this with OpenMP, but this involves concurrency more than parallelism, so I would look at pthreads or C++11 threads:

- pthreads [(link)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm)
- C++11 threads [(link)](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/03/cpp11-concurrency-part1-start-threads.html)

Answer (score 1):

The BackgroundWorker Class

Some good example here:

[BackgroundWorker Class Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)

[BackgroundWorker Class CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners)

Comment: I haven't specified a platform because I am assuming my code must be multi-platform. I think your suggestion is valid for Windows only, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Here I launch three threads using pthread.  It might give you something to work from ... enjoy :

```
// g++ -o  audio  *.cpp ../common/*.cpp  -std=c++11  -lm -lpthread

#include "cpp_openal_opengl_dna.h"

#include <thread>
#include <exception>
#include <mutex>

void launch_producer(Circular_Buffer * given_circular_buffer,
        struct_sample_specs * ptr_struct_sample_specs, std::string chosen_file) {
}
void launch_mvc_visualization(Audio_Model * given_audio_model) {
}

void launch_audio_playback(Circular_Buffer * given_circular_buffer, Audio_Model * given_audio_model) {
}

int main() {

    std::cout << "hello Corinde" << std::endl; // prints hello Corinde

    // here we launch three threads

    // thread t1 reads an input file to populate audio buffer
    // notice the first parameter is the function above followed by its input parms

    std::thread t1(launch_producer, circular_buffer, ptr_struct_sample_specs,
            all_file_names[WHICH_FILE_INPUT]);

    Audio_Model * audio_model = new Audio_Model(MAX_SIZE_CIRCULAR_BUFFER);

    // thread t2 does real time OpenGL visualization of audio buffer data

    std::thread t2(launch_mvc_visualization, audio_model);  // OpenGL graphics visualization

    // thread t3 renders the audio buffers as sound to your speakers

    std::thread t3(launch_audio_playback, circular_buffer, audio_model);

    // -------------------------

    std::cout << "all three threads now launched" << std::endl;

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    std::cout << "processing is complete" << std::endl;

    // ----------

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am now testing with `std::thread` using `join()` and I'm using Microsoft ProcessMonitor to see what happens under the hood. Apparently I'm really creating a new thread each time a new sample has to be loaded, but using `join()` will block the main execution making the whole process as serial, not parallel. This ain't my goal... I want the loading be done in background while the main thread is playing back the sample buffer.

Comment: You only call above t1, t2, t3 one time ... then it spawns off children threads for each which execute in parallel ... the join simply sits there waiting for completion of that thread(s) which has no impact on the running threads

Answer (score 0):

I think I have just solved using `std::thread` with method `detach()`.

For doing so, I must re-open the file every time I have to load new sample data from it so I have now a global variable that stores the filename and call the function this way:

```
// The loading function that will be executed in a new thread
void continuePreload(unsigned long ByteSize)
{
    // Re-open the file 'openFile'
    FILE *fpFile = fopen(openFile, "rb");

    // Set pointer in file at stample start + preload size
    fseek(fpFile, WavePointers + preloadByteSize, SEEK_SET);

    // Read the remaining bytes
    fread(SampleData + preloadByteSize / sizeof(short), 1, ByteSize - preloadByteSize, fpFile);

    // Close file
    fclose(fpFile);

    // Remember how many bytes we loaded
    preloadByteSize = ByteSize;
}
```

Within the Play Event function...

```
// Get the size in bytes
const unsigned long ByteSize = SampleLib.smp.len * sizeof(short);

if (preloadByteSize < ByteSize)
{
    std::thread loadSample(&myClass::continuePreload, this, ByteSize);
    loadSample.detach();
}
```

The program is now acting exactly how I expected: whenever the play event arrives, it starts playing back audio from the sample buffer using what was previously preloaded, in the meantime a new thread finishes loading the remaining part of the file and fills the buffer completely.

As long as loading from disk is faster than the audio playback, we have no race conditions. In case loading is too slow, I can still increase the preload size, slowing down a bit the initial loading time.